# ¿Como llamar un metodo mediante un action en html y php?

Tags: php, html

saben porque a mi no me funciona el llamamiento a un método mediante un action? este es el formulario

```
<form id = "post" class="contenedor-publicacion" method="POST" 
 action="../lib/comentarios/loadRespuestas">
        <textarea name="comentario" class="textarea-publicar" id="" placeholder="Ingrese su 
Comentario"></textarea>
        <div class="btn-publicar"><button>Publicar</button></div>
    </form>
```

Este es el metodo que esta contenido en comentarios

```
 public function loadRespuestas(){
        header('Location: ../HTMLFiles/index.php');
 }
```

La cuestión es que he visto videos de php donde llaman a un metodo mediante el action pero yo no logro hacerlo ¿alguien sabe como se debe de llamar?

Comment: Parece que no funciona por que en el action estas invocando a un archivo llamado `loadRespuestas` pero ¿no te falta la extensión de dicho archivo?

Comment: el archivo php es el que se llama comentarios y el metodo que quiero ejecutar se llama loadRespuestas

Comment: @BetaM lo único que me muestra es una pagina en blanco y no ejecuta el método

Comment: Debes explicar si estás usando URLs amigables, pues la extensión .php no aparece en el action. Por otra parte, debes mostrar cómo recibes los datos en el archivo comentarios. Estás mostrando solo una función que no tiene nada que ver con los datos, sin mostrar siquiera si llamas a esa función. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

el problema que veo es que estás llamando a un método que (imagino) se encuentra dentro de un archivo .php.
Lo usual (y creo que lo permitido) es que mediante el action llames a un archivo .php, por ejemplo recibo_action.php. Dentro del mismo tenes que recibir el valor id que envía el formulario y con él llamar al método que quieras.
Adjunto un ejemplo

EL HTML

```
<form id = "post" class="contenedor-publicacion" method="POST" 
    action="../lib/comentarios/recibo_action.php">
    <textarea name="comentario" class="textarea-publicar" id="" placeholder="Ingrese su 
    Comentario"></textarea>
    <div class="btn-publicar"><button>Publicar</button></div>
</form>
```

y el PHP que recibe el dato

```
>>> archivo recibo_action.php

<?php 
    $recibo = $_POST['id'];
    loadRespuestas($recibo);
?>
```

Ojala esta información sea de tu utilidad.